# multi-connection using socket.accept()

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to connect my PC to 2 RPIs via Ethernet cable. I did a Python code to do the connection with the `socket` package. For now, it works! Yeah!

But, I'm not sure I'm doing the connection in a clean way. Actually, right now, I cannot know which RPI will be connection 1 and which will be connection 2.

Do you know if there's a better way to accept both connections and still know which is which?

So, here's my code:

```
import socket
import time

TCP_IP = '' 
TCP_PORT = 5005
buffer = 15

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn1, addr1 = s.accept()
conn2, addr2 = s.accept()
  
data = conn1.recv(buffer)
print(data)
time.sleep(2)

data = conn2.recv(buffer)
print(data)

conn1.close()
conn2.close()
```

Comment: After connecting, have each send a code which identifies them.

Comment: `accept()` tells you the IP/Port of each device that is accepted. You know RPI #1 is connected to Ethernet port #1, and RPI #2 is connected to Ethernet port #2, so just match up the details that `accept()` gives you. There may even be a lower-level system API you can call to determine which physical port each accepted client is connected to.